# Как добавить delay (или что-то аналогичное) к hover?

Tags: hover, dropdown

В хедере есть блок, на который наводишь и выпадает дропдаун, но по макету, дропдаун находится вне хедера, соотвественно ты не успеваешь на него перевести мышку, ибо когда убираешь курсор с линка, дропдаун пропадает. Нужно как то отсрочить (?) или задержать дропдаун на время, что бы ты мог успеть перевести мышку.[image: картинка]

Comment: Зачем его задерживать, если можно блоки впритык разместить, а у родительского блока сделать высоту на весь хэдер? При таком раскладе и мудрить ничего не нужно, и работать будет наверняка.

Comment: Есть такая штука hoverintent - https://github.com/briancherne/jquery-hoverIntent , но лучше конечно сделать, как велит @rusgeli

Comment: @rusgeli, да, действительно проще так, спасибо за совет, полгода во фронте, путаюсь еще)